# C++ object instance as a class member

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

Sorry if the title is wrong, I don't know how else to name it.

I have a class Name:

```
class Name {
    char * name;
public:
    Name(const char * n){
        name = new char[strlen(n)+1];
        strcpy(name,n);
    }
    Name& operator=(const Name& n){
        name = new char[strlen(n.name)+1];
        strcpy(name, n.name);
        return *this;
    }
    Name(const Name& n){
        *this = n;
    }
};
```

And another class Person which should have Name object as it's member. How can I do this? I was thinking something like this:

```
class Person{
    double height;
    Name name;
public:
    Person(double h, const Name& n){
        height = h;
        name = n;
    }
};
```

But only this seems to work:

```
class Person{
    double height;
    Name * name;
public:
    Person(double h, const Name & n){
        height = h;
        name = new Name(n);
    }
};
```

Is it the right way to do it, and why can't I do it like I thought in the first place? Thanks

Comment: PS. There is a memory leak in the copy constructor. Look up copy and swap idiom to help to it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the constructor like this:

```
Person(double h, const Name& n)
  : height(h), name(n)
{}
```

Then read about constructor initializer lists in your favorite C++ textbook.

The reason your original code doesn't work is that `Name` doesn't have a default constructor (a constructor that can be called with no parameters).

Comment: How to deal with `name(n)` when n must be preprocessed or is the result of some computations ? Why is this syntax so awkward ? why is C++ so syntactically bizarre :D

Answer (score 1):

Your `Name` type does not have a default constructor, so you must initialize it in the initializer list in `Person`. Other than that, your `operator=` leaks memory and is unsafe for self-assignment and you never release the memory in a destructor, so there is another leak there.

Is there a good reason not to use `std::string` instead of your `Name` type?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't mind memory leaks because I typed this code here quickly without testing it, it's just an example, not the real program I'm working on :)

Comment: @tuks: You should care about memory leaks. It is much easier to think for 5 min upfront who's responsible for the lifetime of the object than try to figure out after the fact and patch every place where you leak.